# JQuery set custom attribute from value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose this code:

```
<input id="myinpunt-name"  my_attribute="1"  class="myclass" ...
<checkbox id="myinpunt-name"  my_attribute="2"  class="myclass" ... 



$('.myclass').change(function() {
        dosomething($(this).attr('my_attribute'));
 });
```

and works correctly.

Now I have also another component

```
<select id="myselect-name" my_attribute = /* here I want to read Value*/ class="myclass"  ...
```

In this case `my_attribute` has to read `$(this).val()` .

In there a way to set `value` attribute to a custom attribute ?

thanks.

Comment: $(this).attr('my_attribute', $(this).val())

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/150/

Comment: Thank you @ParkashKumar ! but where I have to put this code? 
If I put it here `$('.myclass').change(function() {..` it is not generic. 
I'm looking for something to do in line on HTML.

Comment: You can't set / change this attribute's value inline on plain HTML. You will require to bind change-event and set custom_attribute on each change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On either way (inline or separate), you will require to set / change custom_attribute's value based on the change event of drop-down as following:

**Inline:**

```
<select id="myselect-name" my_attribute="1"
    onchange="javascript: this.setAttribute('my_attribute', this.value);">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

[**DEMO - 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmuxam8a/)

**Separate:**

```
<select id="myselect-name" my_attribute="1" class="myclass">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

$('.myclass').change(function() {
    $(this).attr('my_attribute', $(this).val());
    alert($(this).attr('my_attribute'));
});
```

[**DEMO - 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/152/)